# Using a Function to plot in R

Tags: r, function, plot, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `EWMA_SD252` 3561 obs. of 102 variables (daily volatilities of 100 stocks since 2000), here is a sample :

```
     Data       IBOV     ABEV3    AEDU3    ALLL3
3000 2012-02-09 16.88756 15.00696 33.46089 25.04788
3001 2012-02-10 18.72925 14.55346 32.72209 24.93913
3002 2012-02-13 20.87183 15.25370 31.91537 24.28962
3003 2012-02-14 20.60184 14.86653 31.04094 28.18687
3004 2012-02-15 20.07140 14.56653 37.45965 33.47379
3005 2012-02-16 19.99611 16.80995 37.36497 32.46208
3006 2012-02-17 19.39035 17.31730 38.85145 31.50452
```

What i am trying to do is using a single command, to subset a interval from a particular stock using dates references and also plot a chart for the same interval, so far i was able to do the subset part but now i am stuck on plotting a chart, here is what i code so far :

Getting the Date Interval and the stock name :

```
    datas = function(x,y,z){
    intervalo_datas(as.Date(x,"%d/%m/%Y"),as.Date(y,"%d/%m/%Y"),z)
    }
```

Subsetting the Data :

```
 intervalo_datas <- function(x,y,z){
 cbind(as.data.frame(EWMA_SD252[,1]),as.data.frame(EWMA_SD252[,z]))[EWMA_SD252$Data >= x    & EWMA_SD252$Data <= y,]
 }
```

Now i am stuck, is it possible using a function to get ABEV3 data.frame and plot a chart using dates in X and volatility in y, using just the command bellow ?

> ABEV3 = datas("09/02/2012","17/02/2012","ABEV3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ggplot2 and reshape2 to make a function that automatically plots an arbitrary quantity of stocks:

```
plot_stocks <- function(data, date1, date2, stocks){
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  date1 <- as.Date(date1, "%d/%m/%Y") 
  date2 <- as.Date(date2, "%d/%m/%Y") 
  data <- data[data$Data > date1 & data$Data < date2,c("Data", stocks)] 
  data <- melt(data, id="Data")
  names(data) <- c("Data", "Stock", "Value")
  ggplot(data, aes(Data, Value, color=Stock)) + geom_line() 
}
```

Plotting one stock "ABEV3":

```
plot_stocks(EWMA_SD252, "09/02/2012", "17/02/2012", "ABEV3")
```

[image]

Plotting three stocks:

```
plot_stocks(EWMA_SD252, "09/02/2012", "17/02/2012", c("IBOV", "ABEV3", "AEDU3"))
```

[image]

You can further personalize your function adding other geoms, like `geom_smooth` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `xts` package. It is suitable :

- manipluating time series specially financial time series
- subsetting time series
- plotting time series

So I would create an xts object using your data. Then I wrap the subset/plot in a single function like what you tried to do.

```
library(xts)
dat_ts <- xts(dat[,-1],as.Date(dat$Data))
plot_data <-
  function(start,end,stock)
    plot(dat_ts[paste(start,end,sep='/'),stock])
```

You can call it like this :

```
plot_data('2012-02-09','2012-02-14','IBOV')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming your `EWMA_SD252` data.frame's `Data` column is already `Date` class. Convert it if it's not already.)

It looks like your trying to plot a particular column of your data.frame for a given date interval. It will be much easier for others to read your code (and you too in 6 months!) if you use variable names that are more descriptive than `x`, `y`, and `z`, e.g. `date0`, `date1`, `column`.

Let's rewrite your function. If `EWMA_SD252` is already a data.frame, then you don't need to `cbind` individual columns of it into a data.frame. Giving a data argument makes things more flexible as well. All your `datas` function does is convert to `Dates` and call `intervalo_datas`, so we should wrap that up as well.

```
intervalo_datas <- function(date0, date1, column_name, data = EWMA_SD252) {
     if (!is.Date(date0)) date0 <- as.Date(date0, "%d/%m/%Y")
     if (!is.Date(date1)) date1 <- as.Date(date1,"%d/%m/%Y")
     cols <- c(1, which(names(data) == column_name))
     return(EWMA_SD252[EWMA_SD252$Data >= x & EWMA_SD252$Data <= y, cols])
}
```

Now you should be able to get a subset this way

```
ABEV3 = intervalo_datas("09/02/2012", "17/02/2012", "ABEV3")
```

And plot like this.

```
plot(ABEV3[, 1], ABEV3[, 2])
```

If you want the subsetting function to also plot, just add the plot command before the return line (but define the subset first!). Using something like `xts` as agstudy recommends will simplify things and handle the dates better on the axis labels.